# What is the $U(t)=e^{iAt}=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\lambda t}dE_{\lambda} $ for $-\Delta$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

> Let $-\Delta$ be the self-adjoint operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with domain $\mathcal{D}(-\Delta)=H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and with spectral measure $E_{\lambda}$. And let $\{U(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ be the unitary group $e^{-it\Delta}$. How to give a integration of  $\{U(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$?

In fact, $\forall A$ a unitary operator we have, $$U(t)=e^{iAt}=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\lambda t}dE_{\lambda} \ (*).$$

But how about the $(*)$ for $-\Delta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the operator $-\Delta$,
\begin{align}
            E_{\lambda}f &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{|\xi|^2 \le \lambda}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi\cdot x}d\xi, \\
     U(t)f &= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{i\lambda t}dE_{\lambda}f \\
            &= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{i\lambda t}\int_{|\xi|^2=\lambda}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi\cdot x}d\xi d\lambda \\
            &=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{i|\xi|^2t}e^{i\xi\cdot x}d\xi
\end{align}

So $U(t)f = (\hat{f}(\xi)e^{i|\xi|^2t})^{\vee}$ is a Fourier multiplier that has only a radial dependence in the transform space. You can directly check that $\frac{d}{dt}U(t)f = -i\Delta f$.

Comment: How to get $E_{\lambda}f$?

Comment: And it use Fubini theorem? $ \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{i\lambda t}\int_{|\xi|^2=\lambda}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi\cdot x}d\xi d\lambda 
            =\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{i|\xi|^2t}e^{i\xi\cdot x}d\xi$

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui : $E_{\lambda}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the spectral components in $[0,\lambda]$. The Fourier transform is the transform from spatial coordinates to spectral components, which is why $E_{\lambda}$ becomes a multiplier in the Fourier transform domain. $-\Delta e^{i\xi\cdot x}=|\xi|^2e^{i\xi\cdot x}$. So you sum over $|\xi|^2 \le \lambda$ in the Fourier domain and then transform back to get $E_{\lambda}f$

Comment: @DisintegtatingByParts why is $-\Delta e^{i\xi x}=\vert \xi \vert^2 e^{i\xi x}$. Is it $\mathscr{F}(-\Delta u )= -4\pi \vert \xi \vert^2 \mathscr{F}(u)$, isn't it?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui : $e^{i\xi\cdot x}$ (there is a tiny dot in there for dot product. of the vector $\xi$ and $x$.) :)

Comment: Fourier transform is $-\Delta e^{i2\pi \xi x}$? Yours is Laplace?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui : The multi-dimensional Fourier transform uses dot product in the exponent. Any different in constants is irrelevant, except that Mathematicians tend to prefer the forms without $2\pi$ in the exponent because the eigenvalues then correspond directly with the variables.